# can't download colaborated project

Tags: unity-game-engine

In UnityHub the uploaded project appears.
By pressing the download cloud-Button I need to set a folder.
After that, it starts downloading and immediatly stops with an error and I cant press the download button again.

Answer (score 0):

**Check if the project is in the archive**

Unity Dashboard (https://dashboard.unity3d.com/landing) - Collaborate - Storage

Check if the project is active by following the path.
Although projects are actively visible in the Hub, if they are archived, they may not be allowed to download.